# PHP: Can I Use Fields In Interfaces?

Tags: php, interface

In PHP, can I specify an interface to have fields, or are PHP interfaces limited to functions?

```
<?php
interface IFoo
{
    public $field;
    public function DoSomething();
    public function DoSomethingElse();
}
?>
```

If not, I realize I can expose a getter as a function in the interface:

```
public GetField();
```

Comment: Warning: if you get a down vote for asking this don't be suprised - check the OOP section of the PHP manual.

Comment: Yeah, a quick scan of the manual showed them only using functions in interfaces. May have just skipped over that part. In either event, I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You cannot specify members. You have to indicate their presence through getters and setters, just like you did. However, you can specify constants:

```
interface IFoo
{
    const foo = 'bar';    
    public function DoSomething();
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Answer (score 27):

Late answer, but to get the functionality wanted here, you might want to consider an abstract class containing your fields. The abstract class would look like this:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public $member;
}
```

While you could still have the interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
    public function someFunction();
}
```

Then you have your child class like this:

```
class bar extends Foo implements IFoo
{
    public function __construct($memberValue = "")
    {
        // Set the value of the member from the abstract class
        $this->member = $memberValue;
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
        // Echo the member from the abstract class
        echo $this->member;
    }
}
```

There's an alternative solution for those still curious and interested. :)

Comment: I'm curious and interested. How to guarantee member's presence? :)

Comment: Class `Foo` should implement interface 'IFoo', it is abstract and it would clearly show `Foo` purpose: to simplyfy interface implementation.

Comment: Agreed, @PeterM. The abstract class might as well implement the interface instead of the final class. Depending on whether you always want to be forced to implement `someFunction()`.

Comment: Using an abstract class for the variables will most likely turn into good code design. I vote for this as a reasonable answer :]

Comment: As an update from the future; further segmenting the implementation into traits -- such that the abstract class implements the interface purely using traits and is otherwise empty --  allows you to prune child classes.

Comment: I believe this is the only correct answer for such question. Because Interface is not basically designed to do what is asked for. Here there is a more simple example for better understandings: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php#95404

Answer (score 22):

Use getter setter. But this might be tedious to implement many getters and setters in many classes, and it clutter class code. And [you repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

As of PHP 5.4 you can use [traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to provide fields and methods to classes, ie:

```php
interface IFoo
{
    public function DoSomething();
    public function DoSomethingElse();
    public function setField($value);
    public function getField();
}

trait WithField
{
    private $_field;
    public function setField($value)
    {
        $this->_field = $value;
    }
    public function getField()
    {
        return $this->field;
    }
}

class Bar implements IFoo
{
    use WithField;

    public function DoSomething()
    {
        echo $this->getField();
    }
    public function DoSomethingElse()
    {
        echo $this->setField('blah');
    }
}
```

This is specially usefull if you have to inherit from some base class and need to implement some interface.

```
class CooCoo extends Bird implements IFoo
{
    use WithField;

    public function DoSomething()
    {
        echo $this->getField();
    }
    public function DoSomethingElse()
    {
        echo $this->setField('blah');
    }
}
```

Comment: But with abstract class you can inherit only from this class. With traits and interfaces you have sort of multi inheritance. Ill add it to answer.

Answer (score 15):

Interfaces are only designed to support methods.

This is because interfaces exist to provide a public API that can then be accessed by other objects.

Publicly accessible properties would actually violate encapsulation of data within the class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot specify properties in an `interface` : only methods are allowed *(and make sense, as the goal of an interface is to specify an API)*

In PHP, trying to define properties in an interface should raise a Fatal Error : this portion of code :

```
interface A {
  public $test;
}
```

Will give you :

```
Fatal error: Interfaces may not include member variables in...
```